# How come my string is causing Unexpected EOF error in onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, eof

Note that I ONLY get this error when onclick is called on an item that contains string with multiple lines, so I narrowed it down to this probably having something to do with new line characters. I am stuck as to how to fix this problem.

All information is loaded from my database. Here is an example of text that is loaded from database that is giving me this error because it has multiple lines (refer to **longDescription** field):

[image]

Here is how my source looks like near the error (note that the longDescription text starts right above line 264):

[image]

Here is the error message in console:

[image]

Here is the function:

[image]

Here is where it is being called:

[image]

Once again note that is works when there is no apparent new lines in the strings. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following statement to properly deal with the new line characters. Don't be fooled by php's function nl2br() because it only inserts `<br/>` in front of new line characters, it does NOT replace new line characters.

```
$longDescription = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'<br/>',$longDescription);
```